# Given temp and conductivity can I back-calculate to resistance, in order to plug in a new temp value and calculate a more accurate conductivity?

Tags: temperature, electrical-resistance, experimental-technology, oceanography

Background:

I used a small CTD (conductivity, temperature, depth) recorder to log a series of dive profiles in a mixed coastal estuary. The recorder logged observed temperature and conductivity every two seconds during dives. However, the CTD thermistor is embedded within the device, which itself has significant thermal inertia. Therefore, temperature measurements lag and conductivity values are skewed and not accurate. However, each CTD was paired with a second TDR (temperature & depth) recorder that collected much more accurate temperature measurements which can be paired precisely with the CTD data through time.

My question:

Can I back-calculate, using the CTD's conductivity and temperature measurements, to get a value for resistance, then use the superior TDR temperature values to calculate a more accurate conductivity value?

Thanks ahead of time for any suggestions.

Comment: It's not clear. Does the CTD use its thermistor to correct conductivity and depth in real time, or are these readings corrected off-line using the temperature readings? If off-line, why not just use the TDR temperature readings directly and forget the CTD temperature?